# Scanning data from file into struct resulting in Access Violation Error?

Tags: c, struct, scanf, access-violation

I am writing a basic program that must read and write information from a text file into a structure. The function that dumps all struct information into a text file works, but trying to scan the same information back in from the file into an empty structure keeps resulting in an Access Violation Error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXENTRIES 100

struct entry{
    unsigned int recordNum;
    char *toolName;
    unsigned int quantity;
    double cost;
};
struct entry dataBase[MAXENTRIES];
int currentEntries = 0;

void initDataBase(void){
    dataBase[0].recordNum = 3;
    dataBase[0].toolName = "Electric Sander";
    dataBase[0].quantity = 7;
    dataBase[0].cost = 57.98;
//    scanf("%d", &dataBase[0].recordNum);

    dataBase[1].recordNum = 17;
    dataBase[1].toolName = "Hammer";
    dataBase[1].quantity = 76;
    dataBase[1].cost = 11.99;

    dataBase[2].recordNum = 24;
    dataBase[2].toolName = "Jig Saw";
    dataBase[2].quantity = 21;
    dataBase[2].cost = 11.00;

    dataBase[3].recordNum = 39;
    dataBase[3].toolName = "Lawn Mower";
    dataBase[3].quantity = 3;
    dataBase[3].cost = 79.50;

    dataBase[4].recordNum = 56;
    dataBase[4].toolName = "Power Saw";
    dataBase[4].quantity = 18;
    dataBase[4].cost = 99.99;

    dataBase[5].recordNum = 68;
    dataBase[5].toolName = "Screwdriver";
    dataBase[5].quantity = 106;
    dataBase[5].cost = 6.99;

    dataBase[6].recordNum = 77;
    dataBase[6].toolName = "Sledge Hammer";
    dataBase[6].quantity = 11;
    dataBase[6].cost = 21.50;

    dataBase[7].recordNum = 83;
    dataBase[7].toolName = "Wrench";
    dataBase[7].quantity = 34;
    dataBase[7].cost = 7.50;

    currentEntries = 8;
}

void printEntry(int i){
    printf("\nRecordNum : %d", dataBase[i].recordNum);
    printf("\nTool Name : %s", dataBase[i].toolName);
    printf("\nQuantity  : %d", dataBase[i].quantity);
    printf("\nCost      : %.2f\n\n", dataBase[i].cost);
}

void fprintDataBase(void){
    FILE *dbPtr;
    if((dbPtr = fopen("hardware.dat", "w")) == NULL){
        puts("File could not be opened");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < currentEntries; i++){
                fprintf(dbPtr, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", dataBase[i].recordNum, dataBase[i].toolName, dataBase[i].quantity, dataBase[i].cost);
        }
        printf("\nDatabase recorded!\n");
        fclose(dbPtr);
    }
}

void fscanDataBase(void){
    FILE *dbPtr;
    if((dbPtr = fopen("hardware.dat", "r")) == NULL){
        puts("File could not be opened");
    }
    else{
        currentEntries = 1;
//        fscanf(dbPtr, "%d%29s%d%lf", &dataBase[0].recordNum, dataBase[0].toolName, &dataBase[0].quantity, &dataBase[0].cost);
        fscanf(dbPtr, "%d", &dataBase[0].recordNum);       //Access Violation Error HERE

        while(!feof(dbPtr)){
            fscanf(dbPtr, "%d%29s%d%lf", &dataBase[currentEntries].recordNum, dataBase[currentEntries].toolName, &dataBase[currentEntries].quantity, &dataBase[currentEntries].cost);
            currentEntries++;
        }
        printf("\nDatabase scanned in!\n");
        fclose(dbPtr);
    }
}

int main()
{
//    initDataBase();
//    fprintDataBase();
    fscanDataBase();
    printEntry(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program gets this output:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 0.344 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Running `initDataBase()` and then `fprintDataBase()` correctly results in a file with everything I need, but  commenting out those calls and calling `fscanDataBase()` results in the aforementioned error.

Since this is an Access Violation error, my first thought is that this is an array issue, but I was able to access `dataBase[0]` during `initDataBase()` with no trouble. This also means that it can't be an issue of the struct falling out of scope (which it shouldn't anyway, being a global).

As shown in one of the commented lines, I was able to perform a `scanf` into `dataBase[0]` during `initDataBase()`, so this shouldn't be an issue with my syntax.

All of this leads me to think this is a problem with how I'm using `fscanf`, which is beyond my current level of understanding.

Comment: Are you really sure it crashes on this first `scanf` ? Reading the code, I see a memory violation access in the `scanf` in the while loop, but the first one seems ok. In the while loop, there's no memory allocated for `toolname.`

Comment: Owen Gibson, `while(!feof(dbPtr)){` --> [`Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).  Who or what text suggested using `feof()` this way?

Comment: The textbook "C - How to Program, 7th Edition by Paul & Harvey Deitel". This is nearly verbatim their example of reading data from a sequential access file.

Answer (score 0):

Your major issue is that there is no memory allocated for each `entry.toolName`.  Without changing the structure, the smallest change I could make is to scan into a temporary buffer, then duplicate the string.   Of course this has memory-cleanup issues that need to be handled.

```
void fscanDataBase(void)
{
    FILE *dbPtr;
    if ((dbPtr = fopen("hardware.dat", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("File could not be opened");
    }
    else
    {
        currentEntries = 0;

        while(!feof(dbPtr))
        {
            char tempName[32];
            fscanf(dbPtr, "%d %29s %d %lf", &dataBase[currentEntries].recordNum,
                                             tempName,
                                            &dataBase[currentEntries].quantity,
                                            &dataBase[currentEntries].cost);

            dataBase[currentEntries].toolName = strdup(tempName);

            currentEntries++;
        }
        printf("\nDatabase scanned in!\n");
        fclose(dbPtr);
    }
}
```

But probably, you meant to allocate space in your `struct entry`:

```
struct entry
{
    unsigned int recordNum;
    char         toolName[32];    // <<-- HERE
    unsigned int quantity;
    double       cost;
};
```

Be careful about overwriting the length of the string buffer here.  You'll lose marks if you don't handle all sorts of issues (like the return value from `fscanf()`).

You probably want to test your code with some rubbish input too.  Your teacher/lecturer will.

Comment: Making these changes still results in the same error. While I admit my string memory handling is messy, the purpose of breaking up the first `fscanf` into just the first int read was to see if any read was causing the error or just the string scan. I found that any `fscanf` was producing that error, even the ones scanning an integer from the file into `&dataBase[0].recordNum`.

Comment: Got it working! Scanned everything into temporary values and set them to the struct variables afterwards. It seems that `fscanf` just doesn't like directly interacting with struct variables.